# Cloudformation won't deploy changes when default param is changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have this template:

```
Parameters:
  ALBPort:
    Type: Number
    Description: The loab balancer port (how the app is accessed externally)
    Default: 8000 #changing this
  ...

Resources:
  ALBListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn: MyALB
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyALB
      Port: !Ref ALBPort #changing this
      Protocol: HTTP
```

I change the default value in the template but when i redeploy:

```
No changes to deploy. Stack mystack is up to date
```

If I change it statically like `Port: 8001` CF sees the change

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Changing the default parameter value doesn't change the existing parameter value in a stack(if the parameter already has a value). The default is only applied the first time you introduce the parameter in the stack(during stack creation or when you add a new parameter in a subsequent update). After that, you need to explicitly set the parameter value during updates.

At the time you redeploy, the stack already has the parameter `ALBPort` set to the previous value of default. So, your new default would only get applied when you create a new stack with the template. You need to set the value of `ALBPort` to your new value during the stack update operation.

Comment: so if I update the stack and pass a new param from the command line to the cli command it will update it?

Comment: Yes, it should work. The aws cli option is `--parameters` if you are using `update-stack` operation and `--parameter-overrides` if you are using the `deploy` operation.

Comment: it doesn't work if I pass a different parameter though. Do you know @user818510 how can I re-deploy if I just change a param? (that leads to create more resources due to conditions)

Comment: Feels wrong to upvote this because it's just so hard to understand the reasoning behind this design.